# Is there an API to read an EDMX file

Tags: entity-framework

If I have an .edmx file, is there a way to programmatically access it? I could use XDocument but maybe there is already an api for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDMX file is only for designer. It is even not distributed with your application as is. EDMX contains four components - SSDL, MSL, CSDL and designer information. First three components are extracted during building application and are stored either as resource XML files in the assembly or shipped as external XML files. These files can be read as any other XML files. The only API (present in .NET) which can load them is `EntityConnection` / `MetadataWorkspace` in EF.

Comment: I found my answer: EntityClassGenerator

Comment: Btw. how that helped you? It does completely different thing then you initially asked for. It doesn't provide access to the file content - it only generates classes. So if you want access to mapping part or storage part of EDMX this will not help you at all.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka: As per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34356848/938668) answer, is there a way to read in the EDMX content into one of the object models you mentioned (`EntityConnection` or `MetadataWorkspace`)?

Comment: @RaheelKhan: `EntityConnection` has all these models as mandatory part of connection string: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738533%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Library for Object access to edmx](http://linqtoedmx.codeplex.com/)

This worked for me fairly well to loop through the entities and generate code tiers from their definitions.. It's really a gold mine for code generation though I wish the built in EF stuff was open source. I can't quite figure out how to create C# objects based on stored procedure results the way EF does.